# No input file specified : Can't config NGINX Alias

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm having trouble setting up two locations in my Nginx conf file.

I had no problem having two locations before adding one with an alias.

Location / with alias doesn't work.
Location /dev without alias works.
I would like to use two aliases because I have two folders : **prod** and **dev**.

Here is my current conf :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    server_name  domain.com www.domain.com;

    root /home/domain/public_html/www/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index2.php;

    location / {
        alias /home/domain/public_html/www/prod/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }


    location /dev {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9000;
      include          fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
      fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

What is happening is that accessing domain.com/dev/ works great but as soon as it's on the `/` location, I get a "no input file specified" error.

If I enter `domain.com/license.txt`, I can see Wordpress's license file.
If I try `domain.com/index.php`, I get the error.

I'm already using $request_filename to avoid root vs alias problems, any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use `alias` in this scheme, but if you wish to run PHP with two separate roots, you will need to use a nested `location` block.

For example:

```
root /home/domain/public_html/www/prod;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
location ~* \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9000;
  include          fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
  fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ^~ /dev {
    root /home/domain/public_html/www;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /dev/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

    location ~* \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass     127.0.0.1:9000;
        include          fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
        fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

The first two `location` blocks are your `/prod/` configuration, with the correct `root` to resolve URIs like `/index.php`.

The last `location` and nested `location` blocks are your `/dev/` configuration. The `root` is set to the correct value to resolve URIs like `/dev/index.php`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.

Comment: I can't thank you enough ... It works perfectly. Thank you !
I didn't know we could nest location blocks, I find it hard to understand compared to Apache but it makes so more much sense IMO. Best regards ! :)